# Prevent Angular2+ from changing the browser URL at all times

Tags: angular, typescript, url, routes

I don't want my SPA to update its URL.

Currently whenever a component is loaded or, router navigates to a different component, the url is updated.

I found that I can achieve this for the router:

```
 this.router.navigate(['/view'], { skipLocationChange: true });
```

But I can't find appropriate configuration for the routes in `app.routing.ts`